# Enclosing HTML Classes in parentheses

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple forum site. However, when I try to write some classes in plain form, the site gets corrupted and I don't know how to fix it. I am trying to transfer the "ust" class from the 12th line to the 20th line in the HTML code below to the 11th line class, but when I open the site, the texts merge. How can I write the code more simply and readably without merging the texts?

This HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="anacss.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Technopat</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#191919">
    <img class="tech" src="technopat-logo.webp" alt="technopat">
    <div class="yanyana">
        <div class="now ust" style="margin-left: 90px;">Anasayfa</div>
        <a class="link" href="sosyal.html"><div class="later ust">Sosyal</div></a>
        <a class="link" href="destek.html"><div class="later ust">Destek</div></a>
        <a class="link" href="bilgitabani.html"><div class="later ust">Bilgi TB</div></a>
        <a class="link" href="sorular.html"><div class="later ust">Sorular</div></a>
        <a class="link" href="videolar.html"><div class="later ust">Videolar</div></a>
        <a class="link" href="tavsiyeler.html"><div class="later ust">Tavsiyeler</div></a>
        <a class="link login" href="login.html"><div class="later ust">Giriş Yap</div></a>
        <a class="link login" href="register.html"><div class="later ust">Kayıt Ol</div></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is CSS code:

```
.now{
    color:#ffffff;
}

.later{
    color:#C8C8C8;
}

.yanyana{
    display: flex;
}

.link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.ust{
    font-size: 100px;
    font: 15px / 1.4 sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,'Fira Sans','Droid Sans',sans-serif;
    margin: 15px 15px;
}

.tech{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 75px;
}

.login{
    background-color: black;
}
```

I tried deleting the "ust" class in lines 12 and 20 and adding it to the class in line 11, but when I opened the site, the texts appeared combined.

---

**Edit**: added images.

[image: code comaprison]

Just like in this photo, I'm trying to simplify the "ust" feature just like I did the "later" feature in the first photo.

Comment: Hi, it's not really clear (to me at least) what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you could describe what you want the result to be like. As it is, the above code produces a menu bar where the items are evenly spaced and centered on the page. What should happen to this bar?

Comment: What I am trying to do is to add the "ust" property to the class in Line 11 and that class will affect all the lines below. It's like simplification in mathematics: xa + xb = x*(a+b) so that there is no unnecessary code between the lines.

Comment: Or I can give an example like this: Instead of adding the "yanyana" feature to lines 12-20, I added the "yanyana" feature to line 11 and there was no need to add it to the following lines. What I'm trying to do now is just using the "ust" property.

Comment: Got it. I'm afraid that's not quite how CSS classes work. However, you can achieve what you want by targeting a parent element (as you say in your second comment). It's a bit too much CSS to add in a comment. Hold on and I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid specifying the `ust` class on every element, you can apply the CSS rules directly to all child div elements of the `yanyana` class. This will ensure that all div elements within the parent element automatically inherit the styles.

Here's how you can modify the CSS:

```
.yanyana div {
  font-size: 100px;
  font: 15px / 1.4 sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 15px 15px;
}
```

You should also remove the `ust` class from each div inside `div.yanyana` in your HTML.

Here's the whole thing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="anacss.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Technopat</title>
  <style>
    .yanyana {
      display: flex;
    }

    .yanyana div {
      font-size: 100px;
      font: 15px / 1.4 sans-serif;
      font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
      margin: 15px 15px;
    }

    .now {
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    .later {
      color: #C8C8C8;
    }

    .link {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: inherit;
    }

    .tech {
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 75px;
    }

    .login {
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#191919">
  <img class="tech" src="technopat-logo.webp" alt="technopat">
  <div class="yanyana">
    <div class="now" style="margin-left: 90px;">Anasayfa</div>
    <a class="link" href="sosyal.html"><div class="later">Sosyal</div></a>
    <a class="link" href="destek.html"><div class="later">Destek</div></a>
    <a class="link" href="bilgitabani.html"><div class="later">Bilgi TB</div></a>
    <a class="link" href="sorular.html"><div class="later">Sorular</div></a>
    <a class="link" href="videolar.html"><div class="later">Videolar</div></a>
    <a class="link" href="tavsiyeler.html"><div class="later">Tavsiyeler</div></a>
    <a class="link login" href="login.html"><div class="later">Giriş Yap</div></a>
    <a class="link login" href="register.html"><div class="later">Kayıt Ol</div></a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In CSS, this is known as a descendant selector. You can read up on them here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/d/descendant/

Comment: I think I didn't explain what I wanted. I'm sorry, your answer doesn't do exactly what I wanted, but thank you very much for taking the time to answer. I will look at the link you gave, thank you again.

Comment: Shame. If you want to add some clarification, I can adjust my answer.

Comment: if u have discord I can try explain what I want with images

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. Can you not just add an image to your question?

Comment: Of course, I thought I couldn't add images to stackoverflow, I'll add them immediately.

Comment: Still not clear, I'm afraid. I created a chat room so we can discuss this. Can you see if you can join: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255984/css-descendant-selectors

Comment: I can see but I can't write anything because Im new user

Comment: Man. How frustrating. I'm sorry, but it doesn't look like its going to work.

Comment: yes it's bad thanks for try